# How do i interpret this timestamp

Tags: timestamp

What does this line of code in xml represent?

```
<time>1573643067</time>
```

It is from a pfsense firewall. What is the exact time or how do I convert it to normal time?

```
<updated>
    <time>1573643067</time>
    <username>user@IP (Local Database)</username>
</updated>
```

Comment: Likely (almost surely, actually) a unix timestamp. Converter [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

Comment: Anyway, this post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are seconds since January 1st, 1970, the so-called Unix time. Use the following to convert that value:
https://www.epochconverter.com/
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time